# React Router 4 doesn't update page

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, rendering, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to make a simple router with React router v04. I have two links and if I press them the url will update. The page however does not change and only shows the exact path. If I refresh the page it will update, but this will not go automatically.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

import About from './pages/about'
import Home from './pages/home'

const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(
<Router>
    <div> 
        <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        </ul>

    <hr/>

        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </div>
</Router>
, app);
```

home.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
)

export default Home
```

about.js

```
import React from 'react'

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
)

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
)

export default About
```

I added this to webpack.config.js already but it didn't work:

```
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
```

This is my webpack.config.js

```
var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
  devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : false,
  entry: "./js/client.js",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties'],
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/src/",
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong? Thx!

Comment: Could you post full webpack config file?

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: Here is the repository: https://github.com/YvoO/react

Comment: I fixed it. It was a problem in my package.json file: Old versions of react and react-router instead of react-router-dom.

Comment: yeah was just writing the solution, also you have outdated webpack.

Comment: Ah okay I will look into that. Was following an outdated react course online! Thanks anyway!